# How to update relayjs cache for a 2 react components which have separated data source

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I am trying to update relayjs cache of a component after another component does a mutation and data source is changed in backend.

User mounts C1 which has data dependency on D1.
User navigates to C2 which has data dependency on D2.
User mutates D2 data.
User mounts C1 again.

D1 fragment is affected by D2 mutation in relation: D2->D->D1

C1 has a cached version of that fragment and on componentMount it does not request for new data because that data is already in relay cache.

How do I make C1 render with new Mutated(D1).
How do I invalidate the relay cache of C1.

C1 and C2 are on different Pages/React-Router path.

Answer (score 0):

The [`getFatQuery`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-mutation.html#getfatquery-abstract-method) method in a mutation tells relay what could change as a result of a mutation. Together with [`getConfigs`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-mutation.html#getconfigs-abstract-method) and your **local graph** data it will construct a mutation query that will get the data you need (without over-/underfetching).

Depending on your graph structure this could look different but here is an example to illustrate. Lets assume that d2 is a todo item and d1 is the List of todos.

```js
class UpdateTodoMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on updateTodoPayload {
        todo {
          title,
          dueDate,
          completed,
        }
        viewer {
          todos,
        },
      }
    `;
  }
}
```

For an extensive look at Relay mutation take a look at this blog post — http://blog.pathgather.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-relay-mutations and the relay [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#content).

Comment: * It is true what you say. But my situation is different: There is no relation between C1D1 and C2D2.
* As an example:
C1D1 is TodoList.
C2D2 is a MovieList.
* What I am trying to achieve is when a new movie mutation is executed on the C2D2 page, and user transition to the page where C1D1 is located I would like to invalidate the C1D1 cache and get a new TodoList where the new movie was added as to be seen.
* The logic to add the movie to TodoList is executed in another business layer I do not control.

Comment: Yes and the actual solution is with forceFetch. I was wondering if i can use subscriptions in C1D1 but do not know how.